# How to distribute test user accounts for facebook apps

Tags: facebook, testing, facebook-apps

I have created three test user accounts for an app in facebook. How should I distribute the accounts to my test users. I mean to open the test user account I have to open it from the app dashboard and press "Switch to". There must be a simpler way I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of login urls for your test users programmatically here:

https://graph.facebook.com/[app_id]/accounts/test-users?access_token=[app_access_token]

Then you can parse the json response to save the urls for signing in

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/